# How to write a collation rule for custom sorting?

Tags: sorting, collation, icu, icu4j, custom-sort

I want following rules to applied while sorting

1. The upper case should come after the lower case for the same alphabet,
   for example,
   i. mike
   ii. Milo
2. Punctuation in the beginning of the string should be ignored and string should be sorted with first character alphabet group
   for example,
   i. Anbu
   ii. gana
   iii. @Gopal
   iv. zolo

***Input***

For the given list of below strings,

```
Microsoft
mike@gmail.com
M&M
@Station
sona
Anbu
zolo
```

***Actual***

Getting the follow order

```
Anbu
mike@gmail.com
Microsoft
M&M
sona
@Station
zolo
```

***Expected***

But, I want the sorting order to be

```
Anbu
mike@gmail.com
M&M
Microsoft
sona
@Station
zolo
```

I am using the following option

**rules** &a<A<b<B<c<C<d<D<e<E<f<F<g<G<h<H<i<I<j<J<k<K<l<L<m<M<n<N<o<O<p<P<q<Q<r<R<s<S<t<T<u<U<v<V<w<W<x<X<y<Y<z<Z [reorder Latn digit currency symbol space punct]

**alternate** shifted

**Other options** default

I want M&M appear before Microsoft. How to tailor the rules, so that i can get the desired sort order?

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.